# Completely Remove/Disable Sticky Keys (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I know there are posts about this everywhere but none have a solution that is working for me and trust me I haven't just tried a few things.  Here goes the things I have tried which is also a compilation of all the repetitive answers I could find.

**First I tried the actual Windows settings:**

1. Open Ease of Access Center → Make your keyboard easier to use.
2. Click "Set up Sticky Keys"
3. Unchecked "Turn On Sticky Keys"
4. Unchecked "Turn on Sticky Keys when SHIFT is pressed five times".

**Then I tried the Registry Editor:**

1. Opened Registry Editor
2. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\StickyKeys
3. On the right side double click Flags and change its value to 506
4. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard ResponseLocate Flags in On the right side double click Flags and change its value to 122.
5. Navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\ToggleKeys
6. On the right side double click Flags and change its value to 58.
7. Close Registry Editor and restart computer.

**Then I tried Renaming the EOA exe File**

1. Go to Windows -> System32
2. Rename Sethc.exe

Nothing I do is getting rid of the sticky keys.  If I long press shift it enables sticky keys even after all these things have been done.

Comment: Similar question.....https://superuser.com/questions/763393/disable-sticky-keys-with-registry-key-doesnt-work?rq=1

Comment: "Shift" does not enable Sticky Keys so something has gone wrong. Try SFC and DISM . Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run SFC /SCANNOW and allow it to complete. Then run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth.  Allow all to finish, restart and test. If that does not work, run a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Microsoft Media Creation Link

Comment: @Moab, I did see that but since it was Windows 7 I wanted to start a new thread as well as adding the other things I have tried other than regedit.

Comment: @Ramhound - My point is that you flagged it even though I already explained that its not the same.  The answers to the question you have as a possible duplicate are related to registry values only as well as more program answers than windows user settings and Windows 7 while answers could be different from Windows 7 - 10 I also tried to make a more complete question so that it can get more specific answers.

Comment: @John - Thank you for the comment as "Try SFC and DISM . Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run SFC /SCANNOW and allow it to complete. Then run dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth. Allow all to finish, restart and test." worked!

Comment: If I make my first comment an answer will you follow up and please accept it

Comment: @BrandonOrndorff - Your question made no mention of the fact you tried the solution in the duplicate.  My vote to close this question has been withdrawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Shift" does not enable Sticky Keys so something has gone wrong. Try SFC and DISM . Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator. Run SFC /SCANNOW and allow it to complete. Then run dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth. Allow all to finish, restart and test.

Answer (score 2):

If you know these above the tricks you know must also know these single tips after the new update of windows 10 in 2020. I know you thinking what is new right? let me show you a snapshot of what you have to do if you try all the tips.

**Open windows 10:** **Setting>Ease of Access>Keyboard>Use Sticky Key>Turn off**

[In your picture you see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjI9G.jpg)  how to turn off sticky key but below the Toggle you can see them if you want to turn off or on you press five same key like **"shift"** it'll perform take to turn off your sticky key immediately...

thanks